# XCode Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, sigabrt, nsexception, xcode9.4

I ve searched many but couldnt find so here is my related screenshots:

https://postimg.cc/image/hyrkzet5z/

https://postimg.cc/image/wj8ntpdon/

Saying:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Everything works perfectly until I insert Stack View in Table View. Im kinda new in Xcode.

Thank you all!

Comment: Could you show full error description?

Comment: I've no idea what you're asking and how your title and that screen shot fit together. Please take the [tour] of the site to learn how to post a good question.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: @SEZINENGUR can you upload a demo of the problem to github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you ask table view to dequeue a cell but it can't find that cell.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, table view is trying to dequeue a cell with an identifier of `cell`. Give an identifier to your cell if it's a prototype cell. If you are using a custom cell, then register your cell with table view in the `viewDidLoad` with the following code.

```
tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```